# How to get list of all matching strings using regex in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string containing first and last names within a text like this:

```
"some text, 'Frances, David', some text, some text, 'Foljevic, Laura', some text, some text, Holjevic, Louis, some text, 'Staples, Cheri', some text"
```

I want to get a list of name '`First, Last`' in the above string. I am trying the below expression

```
$Pattern = "'\w*, \w*'" ; $strText -match $Pattern; foreach ($match in $matches) {write-output $match;}
```

But it returns just first matching String `'Frances, David'`.

How will I get all the matching strings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-Match` operator populates automatic variable `$Matches` that is not suitable. Use the regex accelereator and a `MatchCollection` like so,

```
$mc = [regex]::matches($strText, $pattern)
$mc.groups.count
3
$mc.groups[0].value
'Frances, David'
$mc.groups[1].value
'Foljevic, Laura'
$mc.groups[2].value
'Staples, Cheri'
```

As why `-Match` doesn't quite work the way one would excpect, [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) explains:

> The -Match and -NotMatch operators populate the $Matches automatic
>   variable when the input (the left-side argument) to the operator is a
>   single scalar object. When the input is scalar, the -Match and
>   -NotMatch operators return a Boolean value and set the value of the $Matches automatic variable to the matched components of the argument.

As you are passing a single string, not a collection, the behavior is a bit suprising.

*Edit:*

As how to replace all the matches, use `[regex]::replace()` with capture groups.

```
$pattern = "'(\w*), (\w*)'" # save matched string's substrings to $1 and $2
[regex]::replace($strText, $pattern, "'`$2 `$1'") # replace all matches with modified $2 and $1

some text, 'David Frances', some text, some text, 'Laura Foljevic', some text, some text, Holjevic, Louis, some text, 'Cheri Staples', some text
```

Comment: Hi vonPryz,
Is there a direct way to replace 'First, Last' to 'First Last' in the above string $strText using regex?
Currently i am doing this iterating the output Matching Collection in the for loop.

Comment: @user3835927 Yes, use the `[regex]::replace()` with capture groups. See edited post for an example. For complex modifications, looping the match collection can be far simpler to write and understand than aiming at an one-liner.